# how to use a for loop through variables that call the same function

Tags: python, class, for-loop, tkinter

I'm doing some tests to create a GUI to improve my performance at work, and I need to create 10 entry's and with a button, get the value of all, separately, and in the case of this code just save in a listbox, but I believe there is one way to do this with a loop, because I have to call the same function 10 times with variables of different names and take each variable, create 10 gets and 10 inserts, which makes my code big, dirty and horrible to read.
(sorry for the weird english, i'm translating by google translator)

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk


    class Criar_input(object):
      def __init__(self, master):
      self.master = master

      self.input = Entry(master)
      self.input.pack()


      def getting(): 
        frase_1 = input_1.input.get()
        frase_2 = input_2.input.get()
        frase_3 = input_3.input.get()
        frase_4 = input_4.input.get()
        frase_5 = input_5.input.get()
        frase_6 = input_6.input.get()
        frase_7 = input_7.input.get()
        frase_8 = input_8.input.get()
        frase_9 = input_9.input.get()
        frase_10 = input_10.input.get()
        lb.insert(0, frase_1)
        lb.insert(1, frase_2)
        lb.insert(2, frase_3)
        lb.insert(3, frase_4)
        lb.insert(4, frase_5)
        lb.insert(5, frase_6)
        lb.insert(6, frase_7)
        lb.insert(7, frase_8)
        lb.insert(8, frase_9)
        lb.insert(9, frase_10)


     def get_input(master):
        bt = Button(master, text='Pressione', command=getting)
        bt.pack(side='bottom', expand=1)


     app = Tk()

     input_1 = Criar_input(app)
     input_2 = Criar_input(app)
     input_3 = Criar_input(app)
     input_4 = Criar_input(app)
     input_5 = Criar_input(app)
     input_6 = Criar_input(app)
     input_7 = Criar_input(app)
     input_8 = Criar_input(app)
     input_9 = Criar_input(app)
     input_10 = Criar_input(app)

     lb = Listbox(app)
     lb.pack(side='bottom', expand=1)
     get_input(app)

     app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the widgets in a list, and then loop over the list.

```
entries = []
for i in range(10):
    entry = Entry(...)
    entries.append(entry)
```

When you need to get all of the data, you can loop over the list of widgets

```
for entry in entries:
    data = entry.get()
    lb.insert("end", data)
```